# Can I stream video with nginx module?

Tags: nginx, mp4, video-streaming, h264

**I want to stream video from nginx to my browser.**

The videos are generlly in .mp4 format, but I can transcode either on the fly or in advance with avconv or ffmpeg/whatever.

Is there a module I can install in nginx that'll allow me to stream video to a browserwithout any other software on the server/my PC?

Has to be free, of course.

I have looked, and am getting a lot of confusing answers.

Thanks a lot, folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the RTMP Nginx module. It is a fully-featured streaming solution for Nginx.

It is available in the official Ubuntu repositories and it can be easily installed:

`sudo apt install libnginx-mod-rtmp`

Comment: Lovely, thank you very much.